# PHP checking for array key or using default value

Tags: php

I currently use this code pattern fairly frequently

```
if(array_key_exists('possible_key', $array)) {
    $my_variable = $array['possible_key'];
} else {
    $my_variable = 'my default value';
}
```

Is there a better way to be writing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One quick change you can do is making use of ternary operator instead of writing if else block.

```
$my_variable = array_key_exists('possible_key', $array) 
               ? $array['possible_key'] 
               : 'my default value';
```

Comment: Never thought of using multiple lines with the ternary operator before, though I can see how this would be a very long line otherwise (and it does seem more readable like this).  Is it considered a best practice to do this?

Comment: **Side note:** What's the difference between `array_key_exists('possible_key', $array)` and `isset($array['possible_key'])`?

Comment: @JosephSilber `$array['possible_key'] = null;`  `isset($array['possible_key']); /* false */  array_key_exists('possible_key', $array); /* true */`

Answer (score 5):

A modern (PHP7+) solution in case you want a default value when **either the element is not set or the value is null**.

```
$my_variable = $array['possible_key'] ?? 'my default value';
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to keep it simple and not to use if else.
Just assign it the default value, and change only when the condition meets.

```
$my_variable = 'my default value';
if(array_key_exists('possible_key', $array)) $my_variable = $array['possible_key'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there an atomic way to check if the value exists by a key AND return the value, so there will be just one query to the array? I think that this was the original idea of the author of the question. In a very large array, all examples here have shown essentially too lookup: for example `array_key_exists('possible_key', $array) ? $array['possible_key']` etc...

A better way would be a single operation with the array that would not give a PHP run time warning in the key does not exist.

Unfortunately, PHP does not have an atomic check-and-lookup. So, the answer to the author's question is **"NO, this is not possible in PHP to check and lookup in one operation".**

However, on the question of "is there a better way to be writing this", the answer is "YES, you can [avoid repeating string literals](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1192) and [use ternary operator](https://larryullman.com/2008/10/29/using-the-ternary-operator-in-php), but there still be two operations with the array". So here is an improved version of the author's code:

```
$my_key = 'possible_key'; $my_variable = (array_key_exists($my_key, $array)) ? $array[$my_key] : 'my default value';
```

Comment: This re-statement of the question is what I was originally looking for, and what brought me here.  It seems a single lookup isn't possible in PHP, but Hack has a built-in `idx()` with this behavior.  https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/reference/function/HH.idx/

Answer (score -2):

Untested code here as I don't have access to my dev machine, but taking Sky's ternary suggestion above and simplifying it (one empty() call is faster than an array_key_exists (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884609/array-key-existskey-array-vs-emptyarraykey)

```
$var = empty($array['possible_key']) ? 'default value' : $array['possible_key'];
```

Comment: If `$array['possible_key']` is set to `''` or `0`, this'll return `'default value'`.

Comment: "one empty() call is faster than an array_key_exists" Correct functionality is a lot more important than performance (in this context, though also usually in general).  But yes, if he's willing to ignore values containing 0, empty, `'0'`, etc, this is shorter and a tiny bit faster.  (`isset` would probably be a better fit here than `empty` by the way.  `isset` has fewer false negatives in this context.)

Comment: Ah...true guys....woops

Answer (score -4):

I prefer to use use isset and make little refactor and wrap that code to function/method

```
function defaultize( $array_var ,$defaul_val ){
 if(isset($array_var)) {
    $ret = $array_var;
 } else {
    $ret = 'my default value';
 }
 return $ret;
}
```

and then use in code

```
$my_variable = defaultize($array['possible_key'],'my default_value' );
$my_variable2 = defaultize($array['possible_key2'],'my default_value2' );
```

Comment: defaultize($array['possible_key'],'my default_value' ); <-- if 'possible_key' dows not exists the PHP will throw an E_NOTICE warning and your function body is messed up.

Comment: `$array` seem uninitialized inside the function.

Comment: Ups, sorry just fixed that